# Paginación de tablas relacionadas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, paginación

Tengo las tablas personas y alumnos, el personas tengo todos los datos generales y en alumno los específicos para eso. La cuestión es que si quiero hacer una paginación de alumnos tengo que llamar a la tabla personas también y no sé muy bien como hacerlo.
De normal solo devolvería el método `paginate()` en una variable a la vista en la que lo voy a usar

```py
    public function index()
    {
        $alumnos = Alumno::paginate();

        return view('alumnos.index', compact('alumnos'));
    }
```

Y ya desde la vista trabajar con `{{ $alumnos }}` para acceder a los campos pero eso solo me devolvería los datos de la tabla alumno, y ahí no estan los nombres ni apellidos, los modelos son:

**PERSONA**

```py
class Persona extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        "dni",
        "nombres",
        "apePaterno",
        "apeMaterno",
        "sexo",
        "celular",
        "telefono",
        "correo",
        "distrito",
        "direccion",
        "imgPerfil",
        "observaciones"
    ];




    public function profesor(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Profesor');
    }

    public function alumno(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Alumno');
    }
}
```

**ALUMNO**

```py
    class Alumno extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "idPersona",
        "idApoderado",
        "idSeccion",
        "colegioPrecedencia",
        "numHermanos",
        "viveCon",
        "saleSolo",
        "nomTrasporte",
        "numTrasporte"
    ];



    public function persona(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Persona');
    }

    public function matricula(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Matricula');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente tenés que hacer un [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) de la relación `persona()`.

```
$alumnos = Alumno::with('persona')->paginate(15);
```

Eso te va a permitir acceder a la información de `persona` de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)
    {{ $alumno->persona->dni }}
@endforeach

{{ $alumnos->links() }}
```